# How to create custom CardView with internal FrameLayout on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-framelayout

I was in need of adding a border to a CardView and the way I found to do that (here in stackoverflow) was creating a FrameLayout inside and add a shape background to it. This approach worked nicely but now I need to extend this to a custom layout to avoid duplicating this code every time I want to use this cardviewWithBorders!

The current code looks like this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_border_corner_radius"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fieldInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:textAppearance="@style/LatoRegular"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:hint="Type in your E-mail" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

All I want is to have a component of the CardView and the FrameLayout which I could use like this:

```
<com.example.BorderCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <content goes here />

</com.example.BorderCardView>
```

What can I do to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck that your "inner" view is a `FrameLayout` and that `CardView` extends FrameLayout, since this means that you don't need to worry about the exact type of your child views' `LayoutParams` objects.

```
public class BorderCardView extends CardView {

    public BorderCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);

        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        frame.setLayoutParams(params);
        frame.setBackground(/* your background drawable */);
        frame.setPadding(/* your left/top/right/bottom padding */);

        while (getChildCount() > 0) {
            View child = getChildAt(0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams childParams =
                    (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            removeView(child);
            frame.addView(child);

            child.setLayoutParams(childParams);
        }

        addView(frame);
    }
}
```

What you're doing here is dynamically creating your "inner" `FrameLayout`, and then looping over all children from your layout, removing them from the `CardView` and adding them to the `FrameLayout` instead, and then finally adding the "inner" frame to the `CardView`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!